# Searching an SQL database for rooms within a given capacity

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone I'm working on a room booking system and seem to be returning an error.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `rooms` WHERE capacity => '$minCap' AND capacity <= '$maxCap'";
```

This is the error I'm getting:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> '150' AND capacity <= '220'' at line 1*

Comment: Show us the MySQL query. Abstract away the PHP factor to narrow down the problem significantly.

Comment: Perhaps you've already validated, sanitized, and validated again, but every time I see PHP variable interpolation in a SQL query string, I just want to jump out a window. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `rooms` WHERE capacity >= '$minCap' AND capacity <= '$maxCap'";
//                                           ^^
```

Note `>=`, not `=>`.

See also: http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-WHERE.asp

Comment: No problem. It took me a minute to spot the change in your original answer, let alone the OP!

Answer (score 2):

You've an error is your MySQL query syntax. 'Greater than or equal to' is '>=' and not '=>'.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read the error message;
2. See that it's triggered at `=>`;
3. Look up this operator in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html);
4. "Oh, it's not there!";
5. "I think I meant `>=`, because it's called the 'Greater than or equal operator' on that page";
6. Try it;
7. Query works;
8. Profit.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you found the problem from other answers (>= and <=) but you can also use between, i.e.

```
"SELECT * FROM `rooms` WHERE capacity between '".$minCap."' AND '".$maxCap."'";
```